# United Kingdom emoji with `emo::ji`

Tags: r

The emo package (https://github.com/hadley/emo) allows to insert emoji into R. I can't find the name of the emoji for the flag of the United Kingdom.

```
> emo::ji("Australia")
 
> emo::ji("Laos")
 
> emo::ji("United Kingdom")
Error in find_emoji(keyword) : Couldn't find emoji 'United Kingdom'
```

I have also tried with `"UK"`, `"GB"`, `"Great Britain"` but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `uk`:

```
ji("uk")
```

Using `emo::ji_name` (the full list) along with `grep` is somewhat helpful:

```
grep("uk", names(emo::ji_name), value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] "uk"      "ukraine"

grep("britain", names(emo::ji_name), value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
# character(0)

grep("Laos", names(emo::ji_name), value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] "laos" "Laos"
```

Answer (score 1):

The documented name for the United Kingdom flag is "uk".

```
"uk": {
    "keywords": ["united", "kingdom", "great", "britain", "northern", "ireland", "flag", "nation", "country", "banner", "british", "UK", "english", "england", "union jack"],
    "char": "",
    "fitzpatrick_scale": false,
    "category": "flags"
  },
```

The [emo package that you are using](https://github.com/hadley/emo), is using the [emojilib package](https://github.com/muan/emojilib/) as its base, so you can use this project's [emoji searcher](https://emoji.muan.co/) (or you can just look through the source code) to find the emoji you are looking for.